# Vim highlight regex

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a syntax highlight for cpp to highlight STL algorithms, one line is

```
syn keywork cppSTL find
```

My problem is that on a project that I am working, there are a number of classes with a method named `find` which are getting highlighted, and I want it only highlighted for STL calls.

So I decided to change the previous line to:

```
syn match cppSTL /[^.>:]\<find\>/ms=s+1
syn match cppSTL /\<std::find\>/ contains=cppScope
syn match cppScope /::/
hi clear cppScope
```

And it works most of the time. However if fails in this line:

```
vector<string>::iterator i = find(find(x.begin(), x.end(), val), x.end(), term);
                                  ^^^^
```

The first `find` is highlighted correctly, but the second fails. My limited knowledge of vim regex says it should match, but I can't figure out why it doesn't.

Comment: Just for kicks, try:  i = find(...); i = find(...); ... where they're both on the same line.  I'm curious if it's only finding the first match on each line

Comment: @Brian: two calls on the same line works; I think that the problem is because the second `find` in inside a parentesis - the highlight fails if I surround a call in `()` like `(find(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

The problem is that my regex required a char behind find, and inside the parenthesis, the open parenthesis had already been matched, invalidating my regex.

It works if I replace the first line with:

```
syn match cppSTL "[^.>:]\@<=\<find\>"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be what your looking for. It highlights all words `find` that are on a line that also contains a `::` before it.

```
syn match cppSTL /\(::.*\)\@<=\<find\>/
```

If this isn't what you are asking for please tell me.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. This would highlight wrongly in `util::s->find()` and will fail in the double find example of the question if the type of `i` is declared on another line. But it's getting closer to what I want.

Comment: Can you add more examples of cases where find should be highlighted and cases where find should not be highlighted?